# How to set an icon for Eclipse?

Tags: launcher, icons

I want to set icon for Launcher. it has file named icon.xpm, but its being ignored by the icon set wizard. I tried to change it to .ico file, but it is still getting ignore.
any ideas?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If eclipse is installed from software center (version 3.5.2) copies of the eclipse icon are put into following places:

- `/usr/share/icons/hicolor/16x16/apps/eclipse.png`
- `/usr/share/icons/hicolor/32x32/apps/eclipse.png`
- `/usr/share/icons/hicolor/48x48/apps/eclipse.png`
- `/usr/share/pixmaps/eclipse.png`

Maybe copying the icon in this places (with the right size) solves your issue.

Comment: it does not work (I did not try all of the sizes, but most of them). maybe its the extension? the png is not found by default by Ubuntu and when I copy the full path than no icon is found :(

Comment: +1 for question, I need 3.6 at least for work, and the only solution were to download precompiled bundle. And no icon were recognized for an application by Ubuntu (11.04). Moreover, package from ppa:eclipse-team/..., which is currently at version 3.6.2, is absolutely incomplete for work:\

Comment: so, if you had already found a fix for it, please, commit an answer!

Comment: This answer does not work. Please un-mark it.

Answer (score 57):

I added the icon to `/usr/share/pixmaps` , but the name of the icon was not `eclipse.xpm` instead it was `icon.xpm`

In the terminal:

```
cp /yourEclipseFolder/icon.xpm /usr/share/pixmaps/eclipse.xpm
```

Comment: OK, thanks for the answer, it helped me. As well, what I did was just rename the icon to eclipse.xpm and then copy the icon to /usr/share/pixmaps.

Comment: And if you prefer to see it as a bash command: `sudo cp /yourEclipseFolder/icon.xpm /usr/share/pixmaps/eclipse.xpm`.

Comment: For what it's worth, this should be the accepted answer.

Comment: I installed eclipse from a downloaded installer and the icon wasn't working. Copying the eclipse.xpm in /usr/share/pixmaps/ worked. Thanks

Comment: As a side note, `gedit icon.xpm` is pretty interesting!

Answer (score 6):

Go to terminal and type `sudo leafpad /usr/share/applications/eclipse.desktop`, then edit the file to replace `path_to/icon.xpm` in the following example with the file path to your icon:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=Eclipse
Comment=Eclipse IDE
Exec=/usr/lib/eclipse/eclipse
Icon=path_to/icon.xpm
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=GNOME;Application;Development;
StartupNotify=true`
```

For example, mine is `/usr/lib/eclipse/icon.xpm`.

Comment: tried the same but didnt work for me, the answer for this question http://askubuntu.com/questions/80013/how-to-pin-eclipse-to-the-unity-launcher worked

Answer (score 4):

I copied

```
/opt/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.sdk_3.7.1.v201109091335/eclipse48.png
```

to

```
/usr/share/pixmap/eclipse.png
```

(having extracted eclipse into `/opt`) and both launcher and desktop eclipse icons reappeared (having mysteriously disappeared).

Note: I had also copied all the sizes as recommended above but it wasn't until I copied into `/usr/share/pixmaps` that the icon appeared

Answer (score 2):

Just copy the icon to

```
~/.icon
```

folder and it should work. Copying `eclipse.xpm` to `~/.icon` folder worked for me.

Comment: I tried this. It did not work for me. Ubuntu 12.04.1

Answer (score 2):

I just had this problem with another program, I placed the .png files in the icon folders:

```
/usr/share/icons/hicolor/16x16/apps/eclipse.png
/usr/share/icons/hicolor/32x32/apps/eclipse.png
/usr/share/icons/hicolor/48x48/apps/eclipse.png
```

But still had no icon, then I put one in

```
/usr/share/pixmaps/eclipse.png
```

Suddenly it worked. The pixmap is the key.

Comment: Just copying the icon.xpm to share/pixmaps with the following command did it for me: sudo mv /home/myusername/mydirectory/eclipse-juno/icon.xpm /usr/share/pixmaps/eclipse.xpm

Answer (score 2):

Everything seemed correct in my case, but none of the suggested solutions worked for me, the icon wouldn't become visible in the launcher.

Then I simply removed the comment next to the Icon-line in the eclipse.desktop file and voila! it worked :)

So, my suggestion is, if there is a comment in your Icon-line like:

```
Icon=/opt/eclipse/icon.xpm # fill in path to logo
```

then remove the comment so it looks like:

```
Icon=/opt/eclipse/icon.xpm
```

I don't know why the comments work for the other lines (e.g. in the Exec-line it works). Maybe a bug.

hope it helps someone!

Comment: Hi Jane! Welcome to AskUbuntu. Just FYI, the answers are not sorted chronologically, so saying "none of the above suggestions" isn't really helpful. I upvoted your answer anyway because it looks useful.

Comment: @Flimm: You are right, so I changed the statement to a more useful one ;) thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 0):

Simply, rename icon.xpm to icon.jpg inside the eclipse folder no matter where it is. Now try.

**For more details go through the following note :-**

1. First, search alacarte aka Main Menu on Dash.

   You will see a list of applications and checked Items.

   Go to New Item, fill as follows -

   ```
           Name: Eclipse                         #of your choice

           Command: /home/leo/Downloads/eclipse         

           Comment:                             #as you wish
   ```

## Set path to the eclipse directory where you have it extracted.

**Mine is inside Downloads.**

2. Now, you see an icon there itself. Click it and select ***icon.jpg*** inside      your eclipse folder. (You need to browse through)
3. Now search for eclipse and you will see that on Dash with the desired icon and you can pin it to Launcher or have it on Desktop.

**Dash** -> **Main Menu** -> **New Item** -> Fill up **Name**, **Command** and **Comment** and **click on icon** -> browse and **select** **icon.jpg**-> **close** window

Have fun!