# ubuntu 12.04 eclipse icon in launcher

Tags: launcher, eclipse, icons

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to set an icon for Eclipse?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/40380/how-to-set-an-icon-for-eclipse)

I downloaded Eclipse from the eclipse website, when I launch eclipse, the launcher shows a question mark icon(?) for eclipse.

I tried the solution mentioned  [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/40380/how-to-set-an-icon-for-eclipse), but it dint work for me. I also tried specifiying the icon path in my eclipse.desktop, but it dint have any effect.

Do I need to do this in a different way in 12.04?